# Unable to pass parameter to getter method of associations

Tags: sequelize.js

**Issue Description**

I am unable to pass parameters to the getter methods of associations.

**What I am doing**

I am trying to make findOne() call on an Exhibition model, the model is associated with multiple other models as well that are then associated to multiple other models and I need to fetch data till the deepest model in this Hierarchy:

Exhibition

- Media --------> level 1
- About

  - Media  --------> level 2
  - Element

    - Media. --------> level 3

Each model has a getter method data that has the same logic as all other models have, data method performs some logic on plain attributes of the table.

A sample model declaration from my code:

```
const Exhibition = sequelize.define('Exhibition', schema.def(Sequelize), {
    tableName: 'exhibitions',
    getterMethods: {
      data: function (key, options) {
        if (options.userAgent === 'mobile') {
          return _.pick(this, schema.mask.publicAttributes)
        } else {
          return _.pick(this, schema.mask.attributes)
        }
      }
   })
```

Here is how I am dealing with the data() I get from the findOne query(includes all the associated models):

```
const exhibition = await models.Exhibition.findOne({
          where: {
            id: _exhibition.id,
            status: 'published',
          },
          include: [
            {
              model: models.Media,
              as: 'image',
            },
            {
              model: models.About,
              as: 'about',
              include: [
                {
                  model: models.Media,
                  as: 'image',
                },
                {
                  model: models.Media,
                  as: 'audio',
                },
                {
                  model: models.Element,
                  as: 'elementsData',
                  include: [
                    {
                      model: models.Media,
                      as: 'media',
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
     })


exhibition.get({ plain: true, userAgent })
```

**What do I want to happen?**

I want the userAgent parameter to be passed to the getter method data of all the nested associations so the data method of all models returns me data based on the userAgent parameter.

**What is actually happening?**

But it is only being passed to level 1 association and ignoring the rest of the associations.

Level 1 associations are:

- Media
- About

option parameter inside data method of level 1+ associations is just empty {}

Following are the level 1+ associations:

- Media --------> level 2
- Elements

  - Media  --------> level 3

**Environment**

- Sequelize version: ^4.42.0
- Node.js version: v12.10.0 Operating
- System: MacOS Catalina 10.15.3